# How can I swap patterns in filenames?

Tags: bash, unix, zsh, rename, batch-rename

I have a folder of files with names like

```
thing.y.big.png
thing.y.small.png
thing.xxx.big.png
thing.xxx.small.png
```

and I would like to rename them so that the 2nd and 3rd "fields" are swapped. In the example, my desired output would be:

```
thing.big.y.png
thing.small.y.png
thing.big.xxx.png
thing.small.xxx.png
```

How can I do this in zsh? Portability isn't necessary but it's always nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`zmv`](http://zshwiki.org/home/builtin/functions/zmv):

```
% autoload -U zmv
% zmv 'thing.(*).(*).png' 'thing.$2.$1.png'
```

This will do the following:

```
mv -- thing.xxx.big.png thing.big.xxx.png
mv -- thing.xxx.small.png thing.small.xxx.png
mv -- thing.y.big.png thing.big.y.png
mv -- thing.y.small.png thing.small.y.png
```

The Perl `rename` utility is available on many Linux distros:

```
% rename 's/thing\.(.*)\.(.*)\.png/thing.$2.$1.png/' *.png
```

This would do the same thing.

Comment: I was about 5 seconds away from answering my own question with this.